# Midori not working in some of the wordpress websites

Tags: midori

I have installed midori in my ubuntu system and I came across this unusual problem. I cant visit some websites hosted in wordpress

eg:

```
   https://mehedihsan.wordpress.com/
   https://austinnoronha.wordpress.com/
   https://orwelldiaries.wordpress.com/
   http://majornelson.com/
```

Showing this error

```
Lost?

Our server sentries tell us you probably shoudn’t be here. Maybe you’re lost?

If you’re sure this is the place you’re trying to go, please contact us and we’ll be happy to help.
```

But can access these wordpress website

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/
http://news.sap.com/
http://www.sfexaminer.com/
http://briansmith.com/
```

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but for all wordpress-sites.
That's how I solved it:
In Preferences -> Network I had "Identify as: Firefox". I changed that back to "Automatic" and now the Wordpress-Blogs work again - at least the ones that I tried out.
Maybe that helps you.